# C# Loading correct embedded assembly in resource designer at runtime when there are multiple

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, .net-3.5, .net-assembly

I have some assemblies (DLLs) embedded as a resource (in resource designer).
At runtime I am trying to load them. To do so I have subscribed to an event like below:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += new ResolveEventHandler(Resolver);
```

and then the method is the following:

```
public System.Reflection.Assembly Resolver(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
{
            try
            {
                Assembly a2 = Assembly.Load(Properties.Resources.OneDLL);            
                return a2;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
               // do something
            }

            return null;
}
```

Above code works well when I only have a DLL embedded as a resource in my app because I know which one to load through Properties.Resources.OneDLL as in the example above.

The problem is when I have some DLLs embedded as a resource, I mean, in the method above, once event is raised, I do not know what DLL is in order to load it.

Within this method how can I know which DLL is and load it accordingly?

In the method above I know args.Name contains the name of the DLL to load but is a string followed by other information like version, culture, etc... :

```
"mynamespace.OneDLL, Version=2.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"
```

Method would be something like this:

```
public System.Reflection.Assembly Resolver(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
{
            try
            {
                Assembly a2;
                if (args.Name == 'OneDLL') 
                {
                   a2 = Assembly.Load(Properties.Resources.OneDLL);  
                }
                else if (args.Name == 'AnotherDLL')
                {
                   a2 = Assembly.Load(Properties.Resources.AnotherDLL);  
                }
                else if (args.Name == 'AnotherAnotherDLL')
                {
                   a2 = Assembly.Load(Properties.Resources.AnotherAnotherDLL);  
                }
                else
                {
                   return null;
                }

                return a2;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
               // do something
            }

            return null;
}
```

Comment: So the problem is you don't want to parse that assembly name string?

Comment: @Evk Well not at all. First, I do not know if it is the correct way by parsing the assembly name. Second, if it is the correct way to do it, from args I can obtain the name of the DLL, for example, doing String.Split(",")[0].toString() and then compare it to see what is the DLL to be loaded. The problem here is: from Properties.Resources.OneDLL how can I obtain the name to compare with String.Split(",")[0].toString()?

Comment: Well you should know beforehand what assembly is stored as "OneDLL" in your resources, so it should be not a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have done below and it is working:

```
public System.Reflection.Assembly Resolver(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
{
            Assembly assembly;
            string strAssembly;

            strAssembly = args.Name.Split(',')[0].ToString();
            assembly = null;

            try
            {
                Assembly assembly ;
                if (strAssembly == 'OneDLL') 
                {
                   assembly  = Assembly.Load(Properties.Resources.OneDLL);  
                }
                else if (strAssembly == 'AnotherDLL')
                {
                   assembly  = Assembly.Load(Properties.Resources.AnotherDLL);  
                }
                else if (strAssembly == 'AnotherAnotherDLL')
                {
                   assembly  = Assembly.Load(Properties.Resources.AnotherAnotherDLL);  
                }
                else
                {
                   // do something
                   return assembly;
                }

                return assembly;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
               // do something
            }

            return assembly;
}
```

Please, If someone has a better idea to do it, please share.

Comment: That's perfectly fine way to do that. If you want - you can do this `new AssemblyName(args.Name).Name` instead of string splitting, to get assembly name.